# if not working with wildcard value

Tags: bash, if-statement, wildcard

I have a script which basically has a function and then I am running the an if to run the function if the kernel version is the version I need. The script in short looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

postinstall() {
run some postinstall commands in here
}

UNAME=`uname -r`
if [[ $UNAME == 3.* ]]
then
  postinstall
else
  echo "Kernel version is not correct"
fi
```

When I run the commands on CLI everything it works but when I trigger the script as `sh <scriptname>` I get the following result:

```
: 313: <scriptname>.sh: [[: not found
Kernel version is not correct
```

Line 313 is the one with the "if".

Comment: If you use `sh scriptname.sh`, it won't work; `[[` is a command in `bash` and not in `sh`.

Comment: `name -r` or `uname -r` ?

Comment: To expand on what @JonathanLeffler said: your script has a shebang, run it as `./scriptname.sh` directly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not entirely correct. If `sh` is linked to `bash`, it will still recognize most `bash`isms. (The OP does seem to have something other than `bash`, though.)

Comment: Please update the question in future when you've had your device create a typo for you (frustrating, isn't it?).  I've done it this time, but you can, and should, edit your question to fix problems, or add extra information requested in comments.  However, if you've received answers, please make sure your updates don't invalidate the answers — add, but don't delete, in such cases.  (With a non-critical typo like this, there's no problem.)  Also note that I added back quotes around `sh <scriptname>` which makes things clearer; the `<scriptname>` is otherwise treated as an unrecognized HTML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656678/if-not-working-with-wildcard-value?noredirect=1#comment51258317_31656678), the shell that is installed as `/bin/sh` is not necessarily Bash (for example, on Ubuntu, it is often `dash`), and even when it is Bash, it behaves differently when run as `sh` instead of `bash`.

However, as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656678/if-not-working-with-wildcard-value?noredirect=1#comment51258639_31656678), even when run as `sh` (in Bash's [POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode)), Bash recognizes the `[[` command — though it doesn't recognize some other extensions to [POSIX shell syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html), such as [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

Given the error message you are seeing, it is clear that on your machine, `sh` does not recognize `[[` as a valid command, which in turn means it is probably not Bash.  You should therefore not run it with `sh` but with `bash`.  Or run it without specifying the shell on the command line, and let the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) ensure that the kernel runs the correct shell.